# Active Directory Domain Name Controller problem

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I found this error in my Error Logs today.  I contacted Rackspace Fanatical Support, and they told me that they don't support this sort of thing.  Problem is: they set it up, and I have no clue about Server Configurations.

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source: DnsApi
Event Category: None
Event ID: 11156
Date:  18/12/2009
Time:  04:06:06
User:  N/A
Computer: NEWDB
Description:
The system failed to register pointer (PTR) resource records (RRs) for network adapter
with settings:

   Adapter Name : {7FB36A51-B9B5-4C8E-B8FE-224466B2F9CB}
   Host Name : newDB
   Adapter-specific Domain Suffix : wadja.local
   DNS server list :
      192.168.1.142, 83.138.151.80
   Sent update to server : 255.255.255.255
   IP Address : 192.168.1.139

 The reason that the system could not register these RRs was because the update request that was sent to the specified DNS server timed out. This is probably because the authoritative DNS server for the name being registered is not running.

 You can manually retry DNS registration of the network adapter and its settings by typing "ipconfig /registerdns" at the command prompt. If problems still persist, contact your DNS server or network systems administrator. For specific error code information, see the record data displayed below.
```

Any ideas what this means, and how to fix?

Another error:

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \\wadja.local\sysvol\wadja.local\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be caused by one or more of the following: 
a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller. 
b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller). 
c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any network connectivity issues or firewalls between the server at 192.168.1.139 and the DNS server at 192.168.1.142?  Is DNS up and running on .142?  The error indicates that the request to update the resource records for its network adapter are timing out.  If you think the network is fine and DNS is up, you could capture a wireshark network trace at both the client and DNS server and look at the traffic (you should be able to narrow your search to traffic on port 53) and see if anything jumps out at you.  You could also try manually retrying DNS registration (as the message indicates) by typing **ipconfig /registerdns** from a command line on the client.

The second error also indicates potential network problems... can you manually reach  \wadja.local\sysvol\wadja.local? If so, can you manually open \wadja.local\sysvol\wadja.local\Policies{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini from the client?  If not... again, a network trace may help show what is happening.

If you are running on WIndows Server 2008 (and according to your tag, you are), you could also try running dcdiag (instructions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731968(WS.10).aspx) and the [Best Practices Analyzer for Active Directory Domain Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391875(WS.10).aspx) to see if either tool flags something.

Comment: I can't vote up, cause I have no reputation :(

Answer (score 1):

As for the DNS error, it seems pretty normal to me. Your server is configured to use a public DNS server (83.138.151.80) and it's trying to register an RFC1918 PTR address in a reverse lookup zone (1.168.192.in-addr.arpa), which won't exist on a public DNS server.

As for the network related errors, here's my suggestion:

1. Set the DNS to be AD Integrated DNS.
2. If this is the only AD\DNS server then configure it to use only itself for DNS.
3. If you have another AD\DNS server then have each server use itself for primary DNS and the other AD\DNS server for secondary DNS.
4. Reboot any AD\DNS server after making the changes (just to flush things out) and see if the errors return.

Comment: I can't vote up, cause I have no reputation :(

Comment: +1 - Never specify public DNS servers in the DNS config for any machine joined to an AD domain.

Comment: Generally, best practice is to point all computers at the internal DNS server, then have that DNS server forward to your external ISP's server. If you have multiple DNS servers, point them at each other first, and themselves second.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825036

Comment: Good catch with noticing that the client was trying to update its PTR address on a public DNS server!